# Can a set $A$ still be dense in $B$ even if $A \cap C = \emptyset$ where $C$ is open in $B$?

Tags: real-analysis

To make things simpler, say there is a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and there is an open interval $(a, b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \cap (a, b) = \emptyset$, but $(a, b)$ contains a limit point of $A$. I read that if $A \cap (a, b) = \emptyset$, then $A$ cannot be dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but I also read that if $(a, b)$ contains a limit point of $E$, then it can be a contender as a dense set. So I am confused; does $A$ still have a chance of being dense in $\mathbb{R}$ even if $A \cap (a, b) = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $a < b$, $A$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$ when $A \cap (a,b) = \varnothing$. Take $c = \frac{a + b}{2}$, and take $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon) \subset (a,b)$. Then $(c - \epsilon, c + \epsilon) \cap A = \varnothing$, so $c$ is not a limit point of $A$, nor is $c \in A$. So $A$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

More generally, let $B$ be a topological space, with $A, C \subseteq B$. If $A \cap C = \varnothing$, and $C$ is open *and nonempty*, then $A$ is not dense in $B$.
The reasoning is similar: take $c \in C$ (since it is nonempty); find an open set around $c$ not overlapping with $A$ (you can in fact just take the open set to be $C$), and note that this implies $c$ is not a limit point of $A$.